# Useless Opportunities in Cortex-Plus

Tags: cortex-plus, leverage

I am getting ready to run the second session of my *Leverage* game.

One thing I have noticed is that when the GM rolls a 1, it provides the players with an Opportunity. The only use I can find for an Opportunity is that they are required to trigger some Traits.

In my 2-player game, *neither* PC has a Trait triggered by an Opportunity.

It seems that I am missing something? These 1s mean something story-wise, but they do not contribute to the main economy of Plot Points at all. This means that the 1s I roll become meaningless.

Is there something I am missing? For example:

- Is there another effect of the GM rolling a 1?
- Is there some other use for Opportunities?

Is this something other GMs have noticed? Is there some accepted way around it?

Note: I also have the Cortex-Plus Hacker's Guide (woo Kickstarter) and would be happy if there was some article in there that would point the way out of this problem...

Answer (score 4):

You're in luck. The **Cortex-Plus Hackers Guide** has what you're looking for:

> If the Gamemaster rolls a 1 on his dice, this is known
>   as an Opportunity, and any player can spend a Plot
>   Point to step an existing Complication back to a smaller
>   size die. A d6 becomes a d4, and a d4 goes away. If the
>   Gamemaster’s dice include multiple 1s, you may step back
>   existing Complications by more than one step. The player
>   still only pays a single Plot Point. Opportunities can also
>   be used to activate Talents—see page 126 for more on
>   Talent Activation. (p.118, "Action Roleplay: The Basics")

Also worth noting is that in Cortex Plus Heroic, an Opportunity lets you step up an existing Asset already established in the scene or create a stepped-up Resource. This might be a little too much for an Action-based game like *Leverage*, but it's worth considering.

Comment: Technically, in Heroic you can activate a Watcher-rolled opportunity to step up an existing asset or create a resource on the fly (page OM12), but there's no rule in the basic rulebook for stepping up a resource in this way.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, you can create a "stepped-up" resource on the fly, but as near as I can tell, not step up an existing resource.

Answer (score 1):

I've  only played Heroic, but according to the Hackers Guide (page 111), under Action there's a list of ways to use an opportunity. I won't copy the list here, since you already have the guide (and I encourage others to get a copy, it's an excellent resource).
Also, page 194 details the Heroic rules for Watcher opportunity use.